# Show that no $U$-group of order $16$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$$U(n)=\{x : 0<x<n, \gcd(x,n)=1\}.$$
We are asked to show that no $U$-group of order $16$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$. (External direct product)

I started calculating various possibilities for n.
I used a technique taught in number theory that the order clause is satisfied by
n=17, 32, 34, 40, 48, 60. But i'm not allowed to use this result. I have no clue how to proceed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since $U(n)$ is automorphism of $Z_n$ we can define semidericet product $G=U(n)\rtimes Z_n$ and you can see that $C_G(Z_n)=Z_n$.You can try to reach contradiction by assuming $U(n)$ is isomorphic to $Z_4xZ_4$.

Comment: When we assume $n$ is odd,it is easy to see contradiction since in that case $U_n$ is sylow-2 subgroup of $G$....

Comment: We haven't yet studied semidirect products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Case 1:*** $n=pq$ for distinct odd primes $p$ and $q$

$U(n)\cong U(p)\oplus U(q)\cong \mathbb Z_{p-1}\oplus\mathbb Z_{q-1}$

In this both can never be simultaneously 4, as this will imply $p=q$, contrary to the choice of $p$ and $q$.

***Case 2:*** $n= 2^{k}$, $k>1$

$U(n)\cong\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_{2^{k-2}}$ which is again not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4\oplus\mathbb Z_4$

***Case 3:*** $n= p.2^{m}$, $p$ is odd prime, $m>1$

$ U(n)\cong U(p)\oplus U(2^{m})\cong\mathbb Z_{p-1}\oplus\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_{2^{m-2}}$.

Hence, we proved for any possible value of n which satisfies $ |U(n)|=16 $

Comment: Did you use the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups to factor $U(n)$ into $Z_{2^a}$ in Case 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes, I used Fundamental Theorem of Abelian Groups. @Myath

Answer (score 2):

Take the prime power factorization of $n$ as $n=\prod_j p_j^{a_j}$. Then we have a ring  isomorphism
$\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z} \cong \prod_j \mathbf{Z}/p_j^{a_j}\mathbf{Z}$ ( by Chinese Remainder Theorem). Then taking the unit groups on either sides we get
$U(n) \cong\prod_j U(p_j^{a_j})$. Your requirement states that there be just 2 terms, cyclic of order 4,on the rhs. One can work out now that it is not possible for any $n$. (Perhaps you can dismiss the case of $n$ being twice an odd number first.)

Answer (score 1):

Lemma1: $Z_n\cong Z_r\times Z_s$ if and only if $(r,s)=1$ where $n=rs$.

Lemma2:if $G\cong N\times K$ and $  (|N|,|K|)=1 $ then $Aut(G)\cong Aut(N)\times Aut(K) $ .

When $n$ is prime $U(n)$ is cylic so we can assume that $n$ is not prime.Thus we can write $n=rs$ s.t. $(r,s)=1$ if it has more than one prime.

By lemma1, $Z_n\cong Z_r\times Z_s$ and by lemma2, $U(n)\cong Aut(Z_r)\times Aut(Z_s)$ so if $U(n)\cong Z_4\times Z_4$ then $$Aut(Z_r)\cong Aut(Z_s)\cong Z_4$$

Then it is easy to see that $Z_r\cong Z_s\cong Z_5\implies$ $Z_n\cong Z_5\times Z_5$ but it is not cyclic $\implies contradiction.$

If it has only one prime divisior,i.e $n=p^k$ then $\phi(n)=p^k-p^{k-1}=16 \implies p\in \{2,17\}$ .Since we know that $p$ can not be $17$,then $p=2$ and $k=5$.

But $Aut(Z_{32})$ can not be isomorphic to $Z_4\times Z_4$ since order of $3$ in $Z^*_{32}$ is more than $4$.$3,9,27,17,19...$ in mod $32$. We are done.

For  lemma2 please see proposition 5.3 and 5.4  in http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/Sommer-Simpson.pdf

Comment: @SwapnilTri: there is one point missing in the answer,I will edit it in ten minutes.

Comment: @SwapnilTri:You are welcome.

Comment: @mesel Where you claim $Aut(Z_r) \cong Aut(Z_s) \cong Z_4$, you seem to assume that $A\times B\cong C \times C$ implies $A\cong B\cong C$. Can you justify this? Right after that, you seem assume that $Aut(A)\cong Aut(B)$ implies $A \cong B$ at "$Z_r\cong Z_s\cong Z_5$".